# How to use nth-child correctly?

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn on Codecademy how to use nth-childs correctly. It says that

```
p:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

Would turn every paragraph that is the second child of its parent element red.

So I thought it meant that

```
body:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}

<body> 
<p> some text </p> 
<p> some text </p>
</body>
```

Would mean that the second paragraph would turn red. But that doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"turn every paragraph that is the second child of its parent element red"* exactly like that! `p:nth-child(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
body:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

you are selecting the second body element which is simply not there, if you want to get the second p element in body you have to write:

```
body p:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDReM/)

Answer (score 6):

`:nth-child` applies to the element, not the children of the element.  `body:nth-child(2)` should be read as "every `body` element which is the second child of it's parent", not "every element (`*`) which is the second child of the `body` element".

Use `body > p:nth-child(2)` if you want to style a the second `p` tag that is a direct decedent of the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

Second child of any parent, body, div or ay other container.

example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bla!
        </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div:nth-child(2) { background-color:red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> First child (normal)
            <div> first child of first child (normal)  </div>
            <div> Second child of first child (red) </div>
            <div> Third child of first child (normal) </div>
        </div>
        <div> 2 Second child (red) </div>
        <div> 3 Third child (normal) </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
body:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

In the above code you are pointing to 2nd body of the page which is not possible.